# how to solve error like - npm ERR! Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have downloaded nodeJs v12.18.4 but when i download npm version 5.5.1 using command it throw me error as below
i also tried command npm install npm -g but still getiing same error

```
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-03T09_14_49_162Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to downgrade Nodejs version to 10.15.0 using npm then reinstall npm.

```
$ npm install -g 10.15.0
$ npm i -g n@latest
```

Comment: npm install -g 10.15.0 this command also give same error